# Cannot pass a State props on a component using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks

It's my first question here so I'm sorry if I make some mistake.
I try to learn Typescript by myself after a short time in a school to learn how to use React. So I'm a baby girl dev here !

So here is my problem :
I have to pass a state on a component witch is an object. I'm a little confuse because I use React Hook and I'm not use to POO.

So here is my App.tsx

```js
const App: React.FC = () => {

  // States Interfaces
  interface Iinput {
    input: string;
  }

  interface ITask {
    title: string;
    done: boolean;
  }

  // States

  // State permettant de stocker texte input
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  // State permettant de stocker les tâches
  const [task, setTask] = React.useState([{ title: "", done: false }]);

  // Fonction de submit
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!input) {
      alert("Veuillez entrer une nouvelle tâche");
    } else {
      let newTask: Array<ITask> = [...task];
      let taskObj = {} as ITask;
      taskObj.title = input;
      taskObj.done = false;
      newTask.push(taskObj);
      setTask(newTask);
    }
  };

  console.log("toto");

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Header />
      </div>
      <div className="main-container">
        <div className="task-container">
          <h2>TO DO</h2>
          <div>
            
          <Task task={task} setTask={setTask}/>;
          
          </div>


// And there is my Task component


import React from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

export interface ITask {
  task:object;
  setTask:React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<object>>
}
interface Props {
  task:ITask;
  setTask:ITask
  // handleSubmit?: ((e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void);
}

const Task: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  
  
  return (
    <ul className="task-section">

      <div className="task-title">toto</div>
      <button className="trash-button">
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          icon={"trash"}
          size="2x"
          color={"#2D7B8D"}
          className="trash"
        />
      </button>
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Task;
```

Unfortunatly I can find how to pass my state task into my Task component.
[Here is my error message from Typescript log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJHgt.png)

Thank you so much for helping !

Comment: Did you get any error? It seems like you don't use the prop `task` in the `task component

Comment: The error message gives you precise information on what went wrong: You have a mismatch of ITask expected by the Task component and task provided by App component.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have an interface `ITask` in your `Task` component file which is different from the interface `ITask` which exists inside of you main `App` component.

- Delete that second definition ( the one above `interface Props` ).
- Move the original definition of `ITask` outside of the `App` component body and export it from the file.
- Import that definition into the `Task` file.

Also you have some confusion between a single task and and array of tasks.  The `Task` component seems to render a single task, but you are passing it the value from your state which is an array.  You probably intended to loop through them like

```
{task.map( (single, i) => (
  <Task task={single} setTask={(task) => { /* do something */ }}/>
))}
```

In the `Props` for your `Task` component, you have said that `setTask` is an `ITask`, but it is probably meant to be a function.  Rather than something vague like `setTask`, you might want to pass it specific functions like `deleteTask`, `markComplete`, etc.